# Forecasters strike back!

Tags: lateral-thinking

Three forecasters, Phil, Jim and Bob, come out of their office during a rainstorm.

**Phil**: The weather won't change until the next full moon.
**Jim**: I agree, and the sun won't shine in 48 hours.
**Bob**: I agree more with Jim than Phil!

***Why was Bob so certain?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bob agrees more with Jim because

> it's night time. In 48 hours, it will again be night time and the sun will have set.

Alternate answer:

> Bob is a "yes-man". Because Jim had two things to agree with (his agreement with Phil and his statement about the sun), that's one more thing to agree with than Phil has. Bob agrees with Jim twice and only agrees with Phil once, therefore, he agrees with Jim more.

Comment: Argh you were fast! I'm pretty sure you already knew this problem, did you?

Comment: I have not heard this problem before.